# Javascript nodevalue

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodevalue

What is wrong with this code?

```
var myRutabaga = $("rutabaga");
if(myRutabaga.checked){
    document.$("likerutabagas") = "LIKE";
}else{
    document.$("likerutabagas") = "DO NOT LIKE";
}
```

It will not execute.
I need to find the nodevalue too. How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show the HTML ? what is rutabaga ? an element name ? id? class ?

Comment: Please include your html code as well.. It seems there are problems in selectors

Comment: What is $() inside your code?

Comment: "rutabaga" is the checkbox id, and "likerutabagas" is the <span> element id. I want to place either string into "likerutabagas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "rutabaga" and "likerutabagas" ... ?

If id try:
var myRutabaga = $("#rutabaga");

If class : 
var myRutabaga = $(".rutabaga");

Answer (score 1):

If "rutabaga" is the id of an element, you need to use the $("#rutabaga") selector.

If "rutabaga" is a class of an element, you need to use the $(".rutabaga") selector.

Just using the $("rutabaga") selector means that jQuery is looking for a tag name of "rutabaga", which shouldn't exist. :)

You can also use the jQuery .is(":checked") function to test whether the input is checked or not, like so:

```
if ($("#rutabaga").is(":checked")) {
    $("#likerutabagas").text("Like");
}
else {
    $("#likerutabagas").text("Do Not Like");
}
```

Comment: I am trying to setup a check box so that when checked it will place the value "rutabaga" into a <span> element.

Comment: OK, you might want to reword your question then... Just based on the code snippet we are assuming something COMPLETELY different. :) Does the checkbox input have an ID or specific CSS class assigned?

Comment: "likerutabagas" is the <span> element id.

Comment: The check box id is "rutabaga".

Comment: OK, amended my answer based on your clearer explanation. Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

please make sure proper selection of html DOM. you should use **#** for ID or **.** for class or others valid selector.

```
var myRutabaga = $("#rutabaga")// or use $(".rutabaga");
if(myRutabaga.checked){
    $("#likerutabagas").text("LIKE"); // or use .html("LIKe")
}else{
    $("#likerutabagas").text("DO NOT LIKE"); // or use .html("DO NOT LIKE")
}
```

now may it works !